# php breaks with cr and lf mismatches

Tags: php, windows, notepad++

When I upload some PHP files I'm getting weird issues whereby some php files have cr+lf EOL characters, some have CR and some have LF.
I'm using Win8, Filezilla, Notepad++ and PHPRunner for some templated work (all stored in a dropbox synced folder).  I sometimes use PHPRunner to ftp files across and sometimes Filezilla when I'm working on handcrafted php files.

When I go to open files up in notepad++ it seems like sometimes these line endings change on their own and I need to go to notepad++->edit-EOL conversion to change them back to unix style only.

So this wouldn't normally bother me (apart from it being a bit odd how they randomly change) but in PHP it appears that if you REQUIRE_ONCE a file that has different line endings it just fails silently and nothing works.
So my question is

1) is this expected behaviour of PHP, and if so is there any way for it to accept different EOL encodings in the same source file?

2) Any ideas why my EOL characters may be being changed?  Is it Filezilla, notepad++ or dropbox or PHPRunner that is tinkering?  (When I have the files open I never see notifications of them changing, only happens on restarting the computer)

It's a bit of a puzzle so thought I'd ask if anyone else may have encountered this

Comment: You should show what you have tried?

Comment: So it looks like PHP doesn't like the CR only EOL.  Changing this to CR+LF or just LF fixes it and PHP runs correctly.  I just can't for the life of me figure out why my line endings keep being swapped to CR only.  My guess is it's notepad++ doing it when opening the file but checking the options I have unix set and can't actually capture this change happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any number of applications like to change the line endings; it is considered useful behavior in many contexts. Ftp programs (etc.) have options to convert text files when transfering across systems. FTP's "ascii" mode, often the default for text files, enables automatic conversion. If you end up uploading some files with conversion and some without, you end up with an inconsistent collection.

Notepad++ might also be doing it; I don't use it so I can't say. The worst are programs that will insert their preferred line endings *only for the lines you touch*, leaving you with a file with inconsistent line endings. Sounds like you've been spared that, at least.

In short: Check the settings of every tool that touches your file, starting with Notepad++.